# NSString is not working while creating .ipa but working on simulator and even installing directly to the device

Tags: ios

```
select avg(weight) from ProgressTracker where date in ('2012-09-16','2012-09-17','2012-09-18');
```

Hi All,

Thanks in Advance.This sqlite command is working well on simulator and even installing the app through cable to the device but fails to execute will installing by creating an .ipa. Please help.

Comment: could this be related to different iOS versions? how do you detect that this concrete statement fails?

Comment: Yes, By installing the app via both process.

Comment: I mean: why do you say that this is the place where the program fails? You get a crash? Some other kind of report?